# Is this a misprint or am I missing something?

Tags: absolute-value

What I'm given is this:

```
Evaluate: x = 5, |x| -2
```

I'm thinking they probably mean |x|=-2, in which case the evaluation would be false.

But then again I second guess myself and wonder if they're going for something else. Any thoughts?

Comment: Very strange.  This is a rare case where a photograph of the problem might add something to the question.

Comment: My guess is that they might mean: "Evaluate $|x|-2$ for $x=5$".

Comment: Do you know the definition of what $|x|$ is?

Comment: As stated, the problem is written EXACTLY as I've gotten it. No other directions or information. I'm tempted to go with @Adolfo, which would mean false. But I do appreciate other eyes looking at the problem...

Comment: Would @Adolfo method mean false?  Or 3.

Comment: @turkeyhundt, you're correct. I misread his answer... Thanks!